# Many conditions applied to string in a dataframe column, then produce new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to find a more pythonic (and faster) way to iterate through a dataframe and split a string dependent on the conditions. For example I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["ab", "abcdef"],
        ["de", "abdghi"],
        ["gh", "0"],
        ["ij", "123-456-789"],
        [kl, "afzhkp"],
        ["mn", "qtbkpse"],
    ],
    columns=list("c1", "Office")
)
```

And my current code:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row["Office"] == "0" or pd.isnull(row["Office"]):
            df.loc[index, "N_1"] = "Unknown"
            df.loc[index, "N_2"] = "Unknown"
        elif row["Office"].startswith("abc") or row["Office"].startswith("abd"):
            df.loc[index, "N_1"] = row["Office"][:3]
            df.loc[index, "N_2"] = row["Office"][3:]
        elif row["Office"].startswith("Bu"):
            df.loc[index, "N_1"] = row["Office"].split(" ")[0]
            df.loc[index, "N_2"] = row["Office"].split(" ")[1]
        elif "-" in row["Office"]:
            df.loc[index, "N_1"] = row["Office"].split("-")[1]
            df.loc[index, "N_2"] = row["Office"].split("-")[2]
        else:
            if len(row["Office"]) == 6:
                df.loc[index, "N_1"] = row["Office"][:3]
                df.loc[index, "N_2"] = row["Office"][3:]
            else:
                df.loc[index, "N_1"] = row["Office"][:4]
                df.loc[index, "N_2"] = row["Office"][4:]
```

The intention would then be to have 2 new columns: N_1 and N_2 with values in each.

I'd like to condense all these if statements somehow, and to speed it up my moving away from `iterrows` to something more orientated towards what pandas was designed for (so "where" etc. instead of the `iterrows`)

Expected df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["ab", "abcdef", "abc, "def"],
        ["de", "abdghi", "abd", "ghi"],
        ["gh", "0", "Unknown", "Unknown"],
        ["ij", "123-456-789", "456", "789"],
        ["kl", "afzhkp", "afz", "hkp"],
        ["mn", "qtbkpse", "gtbk", "pse"],
    ],
    columns=list("c1", "Office", "N_1", "N_2")
)
```

Comment: could you add expected `df`? [jfyi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar: just added, thanks

Comment: as I see `ab` / `de` / ... `mn` is `variables`, but to values.

Comment: they're meant to be strings

Comment: @DanilaGanchar: I just corrected for strings

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do to make your code faster:

1. Define a funcion as follows:

   ```
    def func(row):
        if row["Office"] == "0" or pd.isnull(row["Office"]):
            row["N_1"] = "Unknown"
            row["N_2"] = "Unknown"
        elif row["Office"].startswith("abc") or row["Office"].startswith("abd"):
            row["N_1"] = row["Office"][:3]
            row["N_2"] = row["Office"][3:]
        elif row["Office"].startswith("Bu"):
            row["N_1"] = row["Office"].split(" ")[0]
            row["N_2"] = row["Office"].split(" ")[1]
        elif "-" in row["Office"]:
            row["N_1"] = row["Office"].split("-")[1]
            row["N_2"] = row["Office"].split("-")[2]
        else:
            if len(row["Office"]) == 6:
                row["N_1"] = row["Office"][:3]
                row["N_2"] = row["Office"][3:]
            else:
                row["N_1"] = row["Office"][:4]
                row["N_2"] = row["Office"][4:]
        return row
   ```
2. Define the DataFrame:

   ```
    df = pd.DataFrame([
             ['ab', "abcdef"],
             ['de', "abdghi"],
             ['gh', "0"],
             ['ij', "123-456-789"],
             ['kl', "afzhkp"],
             ['mn', "qtbkpse"],
         ],
         columns=["c1", "Office"])
   ```
3. Use apply() method to apply the condition to every row:

   ```
    df.apply(func, axis=1)
   ```

This should return the following:

```
       c1       Office      N_1      N_2
    0  ab       abcdef      abc      def
    1  de       abdghi      abd      ghi
    2  gh            0  Unknown  Unknown
    3  ij  123-456-789      456      789
    4  kl       afzhkp      afz      hkp
    5  mn      qtbkpse     qtbk      pse
```

Hope this helps!